# Can i get a table name and turn it into a variable then put it in a img tag

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to make  a vote thing for my Minecraft server. I want it to show 
 on there as in the site. The database is MySQL.

Here is my code. It's just a test; I'm just trying to turn a link into a variable.

```
<?php
$imageNumber = https://minotar.net/helm/GRANTSWIM4/100.png;
?>
<img src="<?php echo $imageNumber ?>.jpg">
```

Comment: yes you can. about coding show us what have you tried..

Comment: Ok @mamdouhalramadan I will edit the post

Comment: you should wrap the url in quotes in your code

Comment: Just found out i could @Innuendo

Comment: http://forums.phpfreaks.com/topic/175141-solved-mysqli-get-list-of-table-field-names/ for getting table name :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you provided will work fine, assuming you fix the syntax issues and remove the double extension (you are appending .jpg after the .png).

```
<?php $imageNumber = 'https://minotar.net/helm/GRANTSWIM4/100.png'; ?>
<img src="<?php echo $imageNumber ?>">
```

Comment: Also im geting Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':' in /home/a3904382/public_html/votelist/index.php on line 2

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking how to get a MySQL table name and reference the value in a variable, then yes. You can retrieve the table name from the result with **[`mysql_tablename`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-tablename.php)** or get the full list of tables with **[`mysql_list_tables`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-list-tables.php)** methods.

But I wouldn't suggest you to include your table names on the client side.

Comment: Ok i see im trying to get A line in the table then turn it into a val